# Проблема при чтении из буфера "queue.peek()" из второго потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, filestream, serial, очередь

Добрый день,
Имееется код вставляющий(в отдельном потоке) сообщения из COM порта в буфер:

```
while (comIsOpen || !closingAll)
                {
                    if (serialPort1.IsOpen && serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            String data = serialPort1.ReadLine();

                            writerBuff.Enqueue(data);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                          //...
                        }
```

Еще имеется код вписывающий значения буффера в CSV файл (в еще одном потоке):

```
 if (writerBuff.Count > 0)
 {
        try
        {
            using (csvWriter = new StreamWriter(localFileName, true)) //true (я прочитал) чтобы не создавал новый а вписывал в тот же файл при.
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < writerBuff.Count && i < burstRowsMax; i++) //burstRowsMax чтобы, за раз, не впихивал в файл больше 8000 тысяч записей
                {
                    String dataLine = DBWriterBuff.Peek().ToString(); //на случай если запись не пройдет 
                    dataLine = dataLine.Trim(); //убрать лишние "\r\n" пришедшие из COM порта
                    csvWriter.WriteLine(string.Format(@"({0},""{1}"", ""{2}"")", 
                    MySqlHelper.EscapeString("NULL"),
                    MySqlHelper.EscapeString(dataLine), 
                    MySqlHelper.EscapeString(getTimeStamp()))); //первая строка PK, вторая сами данные, третья время их записи(надо для графика)

                    writerBuff.Dequeue(); //если запись строки в файл прошла успешно удалить ее из буфера 

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exptn)
        {
         //если запись не пройдет то буффер останется неизменным а тут выдет ошибка
        }
 }
```

**Ля проблем:**

Если подождать достаточно долго(всегда по разному) вылетят ошибки:

**1** Неизменно повторяющаяся указывающая на `String dataLine = writerBuff.Peek().ToString();` **Update:**(Причем (в catch) печать writerBuff.Count показывает дальнейший рост, а ошибка повторяется):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ....Form1.burstRawsToLocalFile() in D:\...\Form1.cs:line 1704
```

**2** И более редкая, указывающая на строку `writerBuff.Enqueue(receivedData);`

```
System.ArgumentException: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Collections.Queue.SetCapacity(Int32 capacity)
   at System.Collections.Queue.Enqueue(Object obj)
   at ....Form1.readSerial() in D:\...\Form1.cs:line 650
```

Помучившись много часов я сдался, и решил спросить у знатоков. Подозрения падают на то что я как-то не правильно орудую FIFO буффером в многопоточном режиме. Но я ведь не записываю из разных потоков, паралельно. Один поток пишет а другой читает.
Прошу вас помочь, мне, в этой проблеме.

Comment: Для многопоточного FIFO надо использовать ConcurrentQueue<T> - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Monk Спасибо вам. Ваш совет (вот нашел мини лик.без. по ConcurrentQueue<T>   [link](http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-concurrentqueue) ), плюс переход на новый метод копирования всего буфера в массив `string[] writerBuffArray =writerBuff.ToArray();` сделали свое дело.

Comment: Раньше я копировал буффер вот так `string[] writerBuffArray = new string[queueSize * 4]; writerBuff.CopyTo(writerBuffArray, 0);`